# Further stylizing boxplots generated from cenboxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am analyzing censored data using boxplots, and the function `cenboxplot()` from the `NADA` package ([info here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NADA/NADA.pdf)). I currently only know how to generate these plots in base R. But does anyone know if there is a way to stylize these through a `ggplot` format or create violin plots (i.e. `geom_violin()`)?

The structure of `cenboxplot()` is below & an example dataframe, where a "ResultCen" value of 1 means the value is below the detection limit, and a value of 0 means the value = the result value (the line is the detection limit):

```
library("NADA")
Result <- as.numeric(c(1.2, .03, .05, .2, .02, .22, 1.1, .02))
ResultCen <- as.logical(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
Group <- as.factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"))
x <- data.frame(Result, ResultCen, Group)
cenboxplot(x$Result, x$ResultCen, group=x$Group)
```

[image: Censored Boxplot Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to be more specific on what you actually want the plot to look like, but this code can at least get you started I think.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(NADA)
library(dplyr)

Result = as.numeric(c(1.2, .03, .05, .2, .02, .22, 1.1, .02))
ResultCen = as.logical(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
Group = as.factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"))
x = data.frame(Result, ResultCen, Group)
df = cenboxplot(x$Result, x$ResultCen, group=x$Group)

max_threshold = x %>%
  filter(ResultCen == TRUE) %>%
  summarise(max = max(Result))

plot = ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=ros.model, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot(coef=1.5
               , outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max_threshold[[1]], color = "red") +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Just for Example") +
  labs(title = "Pick your title")

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually need to use the `cenboxplot()` function though - it extrapolates the data tagged below the detection limit... im wondering if I can alter the style using that function in conjunction with another (like ggplot) or if that's even possible.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. I edited the code, so check that out. I tried to get the horizontal line to show for the max censor threshold, just like cenboxplot does. One thing to note is that cenboxplot does a log scale by default. Do you want a log scale for the ggplot? It is easy to do.

Comment: Wow, cool. I think this is it! 2 follow-ups - how does the `y = ros.model` work... is it performing the ros stats in the way cenboxplot does? And can I exclude outliers in the `ggplot` but keep `range = 1.5`? (in my real code I have `cenboxplot() = ... outline = F, range=1.5`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the cenboxplot method to create the "df" dataframe. The cenboxplot() method plots a boxplot, but it ALSO returns a dataframe (with extrapolated values). And the code is plotting the dataframe from cenboxplot. Try View(df) in the R console to see how it is correctly calculating the values.  As for the range, geom_boxplot has a 'coef' variable which is exactly equivalent. It is already 1.5 by default, but I'm adding the coef variable into the geom_boxplot method in my code above for demonstration. As for excluding outliers, you can do that with outlier.shape = NA.